# Cannot connect two devices with socket (python)

Tags: python, sockets, ipad, raspberry-pi

I have an Ipad and a raspberry pi. I want to broadcast a simple message from my ipad to my raspberry pi using python's library: "socket". I have a file called `server.py` in my raspberry pi. I have another file called `client.py` in my Ipad. `server.py` should await a connection from the Ipad, and accept it. `client.py` should send the broadcast message.

**server.py**

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = '0.0.0.0'
bind_port = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)

print("[*] Listening on {}:{}".format(bind_ip, bind_port))


def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print('received: {}'.format(request))
    client_socket.send(b'ACK!')
    client_socket.close()


while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print("[*] Accepted connection from: {}:{}".format(addr[0], addr[1]))
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 9999

sock = socket.socket()

print("Attempting connection... ")

sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

print("Connected")
```

I first ran `server.py` on my raspberry pi, then ran `client.py` on my Ipad. However, the following error message greeted me when I ran `client.py`:

`[Errno 61] Connection refused`

I made sure the server was running properly, and I checked where the client was connecting to. It should have worked.

Please help me.

Comment: You can't *connect* to `0.0.0.0` in the client. In the client you need to connect to an actual IP address on the server that the client has a route to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out that there are so many mistakes in that code. I presume that you are totally new with `sockets`.

(Also try putting `'your-server's-local-ip'` in the `bind_ip` and `HOST` in `server.py` and `client.py` respectively if both of your server and client are connected to the same network)

Even though you connect with the server you'd still get greeted with another errors.

Let me start with `server.py`:

1. In `server.py` you are using `handle_client` function to recieving a message from the client while at the client end you are **not** sending anything.
2. After that you're recieving the message from the client while the client is **not** sending anything.
3. There is no broadcast function for sending the message to every connected client

The main issue is that you've not learned the basics of the sockets, my only suggestion to you would be to, start things small and then increase the complexity but here, that case is totally opposite.

You can also refer to this video to learn the basics : https://youtu.be/u4kr7EFxAKk